# How can I match unicode characters and non digits using regex?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to combine two regex functions:

1) Matching characters which are non English

2) Matching words
    without numbers.

Currently I have this:

```
\b[^\d\W]+\b
```

But I need to add this too:

```
[^\u0000-\u007F]
```

How do I combine the two? An example of validation is:

韮韮韮 Hello 123 how are you?

Should return:

韮韮韮 Hello how are you?

Comment: I'm using it as a token pattern for python sklearn

Comment: If you use it in Python 3, [`\b[^\W\d]+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/4xZEyj/1) will already do what you need. In Python 2, use `r"(?u)\b[^\W\d]+\b"`.

Comment: Hmmm based on https://regexr.com/ the unicode character wont be returned with that string.

Comment: And did you select PCRE or JavaScript option on that site? It seems you are not using the right regex tester or just use the regex tester incorrectly. Again, see [**this demo**](https://regex101.com/r/4xZEyj/1) and it says **your regex is working in Python 3**. What version of Python are you using?

Comment: I tried both just now - no luck :(

Comment: [Try this: `\b[^\u0000-\u007F\d\W]+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/KrjOSv/1)

Comment: Try them in your code first. BTW, ASCII character range is also part of Unicode - what exactly are the rules? If you want to match ASCII letters and all chars after `\x80`, try using `[\u0080-\uFFFFa-zA-Z]+`

Comment: Wiktor your one worked best - please post as an answer and ill approve it :) Dzieki!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to want to match any chars after `\x80` or ASCII letters.

In this case, you may use

```
[a-zA-Z\u0080-\uFFFF]+
```

Note that you should no longer rely on word boundaries, as the pattern can match non-word chars now (your previous one only matched "word" chars).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cp2CFS/1).

Note that you should only test your regex pattern in those online testers that are compatible with your target regex library. regex101.com has proved to be a good tester for PCRE, JS, Python and Go patterns. Regexr currently only supports JS and PCRE flavors.