# JS RegExp how to NOT ALLOW special chars AND numbers?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a good RegExp which does not allow numbers at all:

```
/^[\D]*$/
```

Now I just need that it also will not be able to **prevent** special chars like:

`!@#$%^&*()_+-/."'`<>\|±§`

and etc (if there more special chars which I don't know - I will be glad to block them too).

This does work - but it's probably won't cover all cases:

```
/^[^\d^!^@^#^$^%^&^*^(^)^[^\]^{^}^;^:^|^,^<^>^.^?^/^\\^~^`^±^§]*$/
```

Comment: Might be easier to figure out which characters you *do* want to allow, if the set is reasonable. Also note there's no point in using a character set with only a single token, just use that token instead

Comment: Alphabeta - on all languages. I know I can use `[a-z]/gi` but if user types in NON english it will be blocked.

Comment: You might find the answer you are looking for here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50060158/2928853

Comment: FWIW, `[^\d^!^@^#^$^%^&^*^(^)^[^\]^{^}^;^:^|^,^<^>^.^?^/^\\^~^\`^±^§]` is equivalent to `[^\d^!@#$%&*()[\]{};:|,<>.?/\\~\`±§]`. `^` only has a special meaning at the beginning of the character class. Otherwise it just represents the character itself, so repeating it is unncessary.

Comment: @FelixKling what you said prevents `!@#` but not prevents `a!@#`

Comment: `/^[^\d^!@#$%&*()[\]{};:|,<>.?/\\~\`±§]*$/.test('a!@#')` -> `false`, but anyways, I was just commenting on the syntax of your expression, not providing a solution to your problem.

Comment: Maybe it didn't work for me since I am using `Joi` and it does not using the `.test()` method but something else? (Just to be sure)

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/UR0ObC/4 or, if you also need to support punctuation chars from the astral plane, https://regex101.com/r/UR0ObC/5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a version of Javascript that supports regex with full Unicode (i.e. ES 6+). Then you can use a regex like this:

```
/^\p{L}*$/gu
```

This only allows characters present in the `L` unicode character class, which stands for "Letters".

```js
var regex = /^\p{L}*$/gu;
console.log("abc".match(regex));
console.log("αβγ".match(regex));
console.log("абв".match(regex));
console.log("ひらがな".match(regex));
console.log("中文".match(regex));
console.log("!@#$".match(regex));
console.log("1234abc".match(regex));
```

Comment: I am using this using the `Joi.validate()` on Node.js. And I receive the following error: `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^\p{L}*$/: Invalid escape` and this is what I have enetered: `last_name: Joi.string().min(2).max(10).regex(/^\p{L}*$/gu)`

Comment: @Raz Then you are using a version of Javascript that does not support Unicode matches. You need to use ES 6, or find a workaround as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/280762/5133585)

Comment: @Raz Can you check what version you are using? Also, does the snippet work for you?

Comment: Node v is `v9.2.0` and as I said it returns with an error.
The only thing I found that works is something I made manually:
`/^[^\d^!^@^#^$^%^&^*^(^)^[^\]^{^}^;^:^|^,^<^>^.^?^/^\\^~^`^±^§]*$/`
But I cannot be sure that I covered all the "special" chars

Comment: This is also good but not allowing non english:
`/^[^\d^\W]*$/`